# Android get textView padding before render

Tags: android, textview, render, padding

Is there anyway to get the textview paddings when the text is centered but before rendering the textview ?

Thanks

Comment: I would try putting it before super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); or setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); but it will propably crash ;-) Whats the point anyway?

Answer (score 0):

> get TextView Paddings
>
> ```
> int textPadingTop = textView.getPaddingTop();
> int textPadingLeft = textView.getPaddingLeft();
> int textPadingRight = textView.getPaddingRight();
> int textPadingBottom = textView.getPaddingBottom();
> .....
> ```